# Visual Studio Online, sharing work items, using both Git & TFVC

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I use Visual Studio Online for all of my source control. My API is done in Visual Studio .NET land and uses a TFVC repo. My client work is done in another IDE (intellij) and uses VSO's Git repo. This works beautiful, save one issue.

I rely on VSO's work item management heavily to help organize workload, tracking, etc. Right now we keep all of the work items in the TFVC repo and it's proving a bit of a pain, mostly because we can't commit changes in Git against those work items. I would love to know of a way to integrate this if one exists.

1) How can we integrate work item management across both a TFVC and a Git repo in Visual Studio Online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can't have both Git and TFVC repo's in the same Team Project.  And there's not good support for managing (or replicating) work items across team projects.

The best solution today would be to move your .Net code into a Git repo in the same Team Project as your Java code, then you have one team project that you can use for Work Items.

I assume that support for TFVC+Git repos together in one Team Project will come at some point, but I don't think anything has been announced yet.

Comment: Thanks @Dylan, that's a shame... I really enjoy using TFS for my .NET code over Git but I suppose moving everything into a single Git project with multiple repos is the way to do it.

Comment: It has been announced that this functionality will be included in TFS 2015 Update 1.  https://twitter.com/tfsbuck/status/605408216936161280